# Socket room for each user id?

Tags: javascript, sockets, mean-stack

I'm creating a chat application in which I am, actually have implemented the private messaging as well as channel messaging I.e group messaging. I've adapted an approach in which I'm assigning each user a room with its user id as room name when the user connects. Further I am emitting messages based on the rooms. What I want to know is if this is a bad practice? If yes, how? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting your sockets into room is not a bad practice. Socket.io offers itself the [rooms and namespace](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) feature and the latest versions are putting more and more emphasis on this use.

Anyway, I would recommend you to use the native javascript [Websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets) object as you will learn more, have better performance and control over your code. The reasons to use socket.io becomes less relevant over the time (IE8, flash, http polling...).

Using room is only partitionning your client sockets: it is just fine to do this by indexing arrays inside objects.

About NodeJS, I would go with [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would definitely look into web sockets. I've read about it, not throughly though. My project is on Mean Stack so most of the people recommended socket io. I've seen some issues as well while implementing. Plus the documentation is scarce as well. Maybe it was the first time I was using sockets. I have some features to add in the project though. Can you please highlight how web sockets are better? What flexibility would I achieve if I use them instead of the current?

Comment: Also I was opting for the other approach you mentioned, that is to save the socket ids in an array and emit to those but that seemed like an immature and complicated approach to me. I read about the issues regarding that approach as well when client disconnect.

Comment: Socket.io uses the native websocket each time it is compatible with the client. It is just an additionnal layer less and less useful. I personally find the team less reactive and I think the project is slowly dying. In these circumstances, it seems obvious to me to choose the native functionality. If you encounter difficulties, it won't be because of an unstable library. Regarding the approach to send message, that exactly what socket.io is doing behind the scene : saving sockets in arrays and emit to them.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the technique used in the question is not considered as a bad practice. Many people have started using this technique and have taken advantage of rooms. However, instead of user id, username or email can be taken for the purpose of each user assigned as a socket. That because it is not preferable to get id on the client side.